# jQuery won't fade in span

Tags: jquery, html, replace, fadein

I have some trouble fading in a span after hiding it and replacing it's contents.

Here is my html before replacing it

```
<span id="replace_with_editor">
    <a id="edit_button" class="btn btn-success" href="thread.php">Post ny tråd</a>
</span>
```

Here is my jQuery code

```
replace_with_editor = $('#replace_with_editor');
    $('#edit_button').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        replace_with_editor.hide();
        replace_with_editor.html('<form role="form" method="post" action="process/submit_thread.php"><div class="form-group"><label for="Title">Tittel</label><input id="thread_title" name="thread_title" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Skriv en tittel for tråden."></div><div class="form-group"><label for="Svar">Tråd</label><textarea id="thread_editor" name="thread_content" rows="10" class="form-control"></textarea></div><input type="hidden" value="category_id" name="category_id"><input type="hidden" value="forum_id" name="forum_id"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Post tråd</button></form>');
        replace_with_editor.fadeIn(2000);
    });
```

For some reason when i try this script, the new content shows up but the fadeIn() doesnt work, it shows up instant.

Any guess what i am doing wrong? Oh and the jQuery is not nested because of debugging.
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try passing a callback you your hide function like that.

```
replace_with_editor = $('#replace_with_editor');
    $('#edit_button').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        replace_with_editor.hide(function(){
        replace_with_editor.html('<form role="form" method="post" action="process/submit_thread.php"><div class="form-group"><label for="Title">Tittel</label><input id="thread_title" name="thread_title" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Skriv en tittel for tråden."></div><div class="form-group"><label for="Svar">Tråd</label><textarea id="thread_editor" name="thread_content" rows="10" class="form-control"></textarea></div><input type="hidden" value="category_id" name="category_id"><input type="hidden" value="forum_id" name="forum_id"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Post tråd</button></form>');
        replace_with_editor.fadeIn(2000);
});
    });
```

also i added a jsfiddle to show you if that what you wanted to get.
http://jsfiddle.net/JfGZM/

Comment: Ok i tried now to fade it out and now i have the same problem.
Have a look at this

http://jsfiddle.net/Danbannan/sQmaf/